# How to deselect selected cell in UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

Normally, when I touch UITableViewCell, then UITableViewCell is selected and highlighted.

But, again touch exactly same UITableViewCell, then nothing happen.

I want that if I touch selected UITableViewCell, then UITableVIewCell to deselect.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        guard let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) else { return }
        if cell.isSelected == true {
            cell.isSelected = false
        }
    }
```

/////

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        guard let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) else { return }
        if cell.isSelected == false {
            cell.isSelected = true
        } else {
            cell.isSelected = false
        }
    }
```

Both source code does not working. How do I fix this method?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Minimal working example (first 7 cells are selectable):

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class MyTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var selectedIndexPath: IndexPath? = nil

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 7
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        return UITableViewCell()
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if selectedIndexPath == indexPath {
            // it was already selected
            selectedIndexPath = nil
            tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false)
        } else {
            // wasn't yet selected, so let's remember it
            selectedIndexPath = indexPath
        }
    }
}

// Present the view controller in the Live View window
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = MyTableViewController()
```

Comment: In case you want a multiselect, you will have to keep an array of selected indexPaths..

Comment: in the case of multiselect you need to add this piece of code:


```func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        selectedIndexPath = nil

    }```